# Jquery is not working in Google chrome

Tags: jquery

```
 $.getScript('Scripts/TEST/jquery-1.10.2.js', function () {
     $.getScript('Scripts/TEST/jquery-ui.js', function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
     });
 });
```

This is working on IE but not working in google chrome .

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  *What* doesn't work?  Does the 1st script load?  Does the 2nd?  Does `.accordion()` not work?  What does it do?  Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: How is `$.getScript()` available before you're loading jQuery? You're not loading two versions of jQuery at the same time, are you?

Comment: @Juhana: Good catch, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: @Juhana.. good one, even i didn't notice that :)

Comment: I mean my script is working on IE ,i mean i am getting Acordon.But in google chrome $("#accordion").accordion() this is not working i mean i am not geeting acordn

Comment: @Sohel: The question I am asking is what does it do in Chrome?  What are you seeing compared to what you expect to see?  Are there any errors?  "Not working" doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: in which version of IE is it working ? `getScript()` itself should throw an error unless you downloaded jquery some where else before your code that your just posted. Do you see any errors in Dev Tools > Console ?

Comment: I see an error in Google chrome ,it shows that it's   accordion() is undefined function.

Comment: I mean Scripts/TEST/jquery-1.10.2.js is not working ,since Scripts/TEST/jquery-ui.js is related to jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: if you look at API [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), it says `The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed.`. I believe that's what is happening in your case, your `jquery-ui.js` is downloaded but not executed and the callback is invoked where you're calling `accordion()` which will throw an error

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript('Scripts/TEST/jquery-1.10.2.js', function () {
            $.getScript('Scripts/TEST/jquery-ui.js', function () {

                
                    alert("Loaded")
                   
               
                try {
                    $("#accordion").accordion();
                }
                catch (err) {
                   alert(err)
                }
                
            });
        });
Here all Jquery is loading but not executed here

Comment: Arkantos my Call back function in which i called Acordon is not working in google chrome

Comment: Hmmm.. i think you're loading `jquery.js` some where else already. check in your code if there're any `script` tags with `src` as jquery.js. Coming to your question, as you're using $ already, jquery.js must have been downloaded and is available in your cache. so the next time your ask for jquery.js, the one from cache will be served and your callback is immediately invoked, but same thing doesn't hold for `jquery-ui.js`. As it's not in cache, it will be downloaded and after download, your callback in invoked. At this point, you have `jquery-ui.js` in cache but not necessarily executed.

Comment: I suggest you use some script loader like LABjs /CurlJS / requireJS

Comment: Yes,in master i page i used Jquery.js

Comment: I think the reason why your code is working in IE is because in old browsers, scripts are immediately executed once they're downloaded but in new browsers like chrome, they try to defer the execution to some later time. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Why are you even doing this in the first place?  Why not just add jQuery and jQueryUI as `<script>` tags in your `<head>`?

Comment: But if i call directly <script src="Scripts/TEST/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> then its working

Comment: is that direct script src `jquery-1.10.2.js` or `jquery-ui.js` ?

Comment: I am not using in Head because I have a Custom Javascript File which is related to old Jquery File.If add New Jquery File in Head then old Custom Javascript File is not working

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the way, your accordion is invoked. According to API [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

> The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not
>   necessarily executed.

In your case, the callback for `jquery-ui.js` is invoked right after the download is complete but before the script is executed. In latest browsers like Chrome, they download the script but try to defer the execution until DOM ready.

You can solve this in 2 ways.

1. Add the `jquery-ui.js` dependency directly right after your
   `jquery.js`
2. You can use a script loader like LABjs/requireJS

If you're using [LABjs](https://github.com/getify/LABjs), then you can do something like this

```
  <!-- download LABjs directly -->
  <script src="LAB.js"></script>
  <!-- use LAB to download other dependencies -->
  <script>
     $LAB
       .script("Scripts/TEST/jquery-1.10.2.js").wait()
       .script("Scripts/TEST/jquery-ui.js")
       .wait(function(){
          $("#accordion").accordion();
       });
  </script>
```

Comment: I have a question where Javascript load when i use src=?

Comment: in case this solves your issue, pls feel free to accept and upvote ;)